# Rails best practice to use polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, polymorphism

I'm actually creating a taxonomy system into my application. Here is my tables schema :

**Taxonomies**

```
class CreateTaxonomies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :taxonomies do |t|
      t.references :taxonomable, polymorphic: true
      t.integer :term_id
    end
  end
end
```

**Terms**

```
class CreateTerms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :terms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.integer :parent_id, default: 0
    end
  end
end
```

and here are my associations :

```
class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taxonomable, polymorphic: true
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled // because I use type as table field
  has_many :taxonomies, as: :taxonomable
end
```

To make it more generic, I create a concern :

```
module Taxonomable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :taxonomies, as: :taxonomable
  end

  def get_associate_terms
    terms  = self.taxonomies.map { |t| t.term_id }
    taxonomies = Term.find terms
  end
end
```

and I'm including it into my model :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Taxonomable
end
```

It works fine and I can retreive the associated data using `get_associate_terms`. My problem is located within my controller and my form. I'm actually saving it like that :

```
# posts/_form.html.haml
= f.select :taxonomy_ids, @categories.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, class: 'form-control'

# PostsController
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new( post_params )
  if @post.save
    @post.taxonomies.create( term_id: params[:post][:taxonomy_ids] )
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This create method is saving the data correctly but if you take a look at the params attribute, you will see that the object `taxonomies` is waiting for a `term_id` but I can only use `taxonomy_ids` in my form. It feels kind of dirty and I wanted to have your point of view to avoid hacking around like that.

Also, and I think this problem is linked with the one above, when editing my item, the select box is not checked the actual matching category associate to the current post.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks a lot

EDIT :
Here is my form

```
= form_for @post, url: posts_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.select :taxonomy_ids, @categories.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, class: 'form-control'
```

EDIT 2 :
I added the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to my concern as it :

```
module Taxonomable
  include do
    has_many :taxonomies, as: :taxonomable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :taxonomies
  end
end
```

and then used `fields_for` in my form :

```
= f.fields_for :taxonomies_attributes do |taxo|
  = taxo.label :term_id, 'Categories'
  = taxo.select :term_id, @categories.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, class: 'form-control'
```

When submitting the form, I receive it :

```
"post"=>{"type"=>"blog", "taxonomies_attributes"=>{"term_id"=>"2"}, "reference"=>"TGKHLKJ-567TYGJGK", "name"=>"My super post"
```

However, when the post has been saved with success, the associations are not. Any ideas???

**EDIT 3 :**
In my controller, I added this :

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(
    taxonomies_attributes: [:term_id]
  )
end
```

When submitting the form, I've got the following error :

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

According to that post [Rails 4 nested form - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037803/rails-4-nested-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-integer), it's because I'm using `taxonomies_attributes` in my `fields_for` as:

```
= f.fields_for :taxonomies_attributes do |taxo|
```

However, if I remove it to :

```
= f.fields_for :taxonomies do |taxo|
```

The block is displaying nothing except the div wrapping it :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Should be display here but nothing -->
</div>
```

**EDIT 4 :**
Finally make it works. The fact that the select box was not showing came from the fact that when creating a new resource, my `@post` has no taxonomies. Doing the following fix that :

```
def new
  @product    = current_user.products.new
  category    = @product.taxonomies.build
end
```

thanks to everyone

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I would like know if there is a better way to  save this polymorphic association? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but one thing I noticed is that you don't really need to save in two steps.

Just add the following line to your `Taxonomable` module (Rails 3)

```
attr_accessible :taxonomies_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :taxonomies
```

If you are using Rails 4, add only the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your `Taxonomable` module and each of the Controllers, make sure to allow taxonomies attributes. For example, in your `PostsController`, add the following to your

```
 def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:name, taxonomies_attributes: [:name])
 end
```

Your create will change to:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new( post_params )
  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This is assuming that your form uses the proper nesting via `fields_for` - I am not sure about that since you didn't post the form code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think I'm close to what I want to achieve. However, I'm still confuse about the `fields_for`. I edited my post adding my actual form. If you could explain in more detail, that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `attr_accessible :taxonomies_attributes` earlier

Comment: what if i'm using rails 4? do i need to use the gem for that or is there a trick? thank

Comment: Rails 4 uses strong params, so you need to get your nested attributes to work with this mechanism. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4

Comment: Thanks. I added this `params.require(:product).permit(taxonomies_attributes: [:term_id])` to my posts_controller, but when I submit my form, I've got this : `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error. :(

Comment: this post fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037803/rails-4-nested-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-integer . However, in my fields_for, if I just use `:taxonomies` instead of `:taxonomies_attributes`, the block (label + select) is not display, there is nothing

Comment: Just open a new topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086349/rails-4-nested-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-integer/ Making progress. I might found why it's not working. However, I still don't know how to fix it